# Where do Cron error message go?

Tags: cron

I have a python script running by cron. For what ever reason, it is not running. I am wondering if there is anywhere that error messages are sent? Script runs fine by itself. If I run a simple script with crontab, that just writes to a file that works also.

My crontab is:

```
*/15 * * * * python ./home/pi/foo/bar.pyw
```

Comment: Ok, I figured out the issue with my script. I was calling modules which were in the same directory as the bar.pyw script. I changed the working directory with os.chdir("some location"). I still however would like to know where the error messages go for crontabs

Answer (score 27):

By default, the logging for the `cron` daemon is not enabled in Debian (I assume it is the system you are using). To enable it, please open the file `/etc/rsyslog.conf` via

```
$ vi /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

and uncomment the line

```
# cron.*                          /var/log/cron.log
```

After that, you need to restart `rsyslog` via

```
$ /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
```

and you will find the cron logs in `/var/log/cron.log`

Source: [Enable crontab logging in Debian Linux](http://journal.happy-coding.com/enable-crontab-logging-in-debian-linux/)

Comment: Alf: Thank you for your reply. I have now implemented cron logging and have alter the command in my crontab to [Code] */3 * * * * /usr/bin/sudo -H /home/pi/ahbc [/code] The sudo -H is something I found on the web which I am told works. I don't understand just what the -H is there for. I have been given to understand that if one does not include the uservin a crontab command line that command will run using the user/owner of crontab. Therefore as my crontab is user pi crontab the contained commands will run for pi.

Comment: the link is broken now :(

Comment: @Michael The explanation here should be enough to achieve logging. Do you need something else?

Comment: @ElanHasson Anything that generates extra writes to the SD card and is a low priority is generally disabled on the rPi.

Comment: I've just posted an edit request for the link, it looks like the source site just changed it's setup a bit.

Comment: If you want to monitor it is real time, use   tail -f /syslog

Answer (score 4):

Crontab has several parameters (in additional to time execution lines)
For example:

```
MAILTO="you@example.com"
SHELL="/bin/bash"
```