# crontab schedule .py file

Tags: pi-3b+, cron, python-3

I am attempting to run a scheduled .py file every 5 minutes with crontab but I don't think it's working.

I'm following this post with the instructions:
[Can't run python script from cron](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29033/cant-run-python-script-from-cron)

I opened up terminal and ran `crontab -e`, adding in:

```
5 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Desktop/BacTest/test3.py
```

to the crontab file.

I then saved the crontab with Ctrl-X, then Y, then ENTER.

Nothing appears to happen, even after a reboot... There is a SQLite database file that the test3.py file is supposed to update, but I don't see the updates happening. At least when I right click on the .py file and .db to view the properties there isn't any change to the last access/modification/permission change, or size of the SQLite .db file. However, if I open up terminal in the `/home/pi/Desktop/BacTest` and run the `test3.py` file it all works fine...

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

***EDIT***
This is the test3.py file where I am using a python package called BAC0 to access a building automation system. Its really pretty simple where I can retrieve 2 data points (gas usage & outdoor temp) from the hot water system and save to SQLite on pi. BAC0 has a `.save()` that defaults to SQLite. In terminal on pi when I run the test3.py file it works just fine...

```
import BAC0
import pandas as pd

bacnet = BAC0.connect(ip='10.30.4.104/16')
hws = BAC0.device('100:99', 30099, bacnet, poll=0)

hws['THERM'].poll()
hws['OA-T'].poll()


print(hws['OA-T'], hws['THERM'])

hws.save()
```

Comment: In test3.py have you given the full path to the db file?

Comment: What if you replace '/use/bin/python' with 'python'

Comment: Also add an ampersand (&) to the end to allow the task to background.  5 * * * * python ~/Desktop/BacTest/test3.py &

Comment: Ill try this... Does it look correct? `5 * * * * python /home/pi/Desktop/BacTest/test3.py &` Thanks!

Comment: The & is pointless in a crontab and you should always give the full path to programs and files in crontab.

Comment: That didnt appear to work, Ill edit the post to include .py file. Thanks for your help guys much appreciation...

Comment: I am not familiar with `BAC0`, so let me ask, does your code needs root rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
crontab -e
```

This works for me:

```
0 4 * * * sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now    # Reboot everynight at 0400

00,30 06-23 * * * sudo /home/pi/python/scripts/router/DD-WRT_UpgradeCheck.py
```

Comment: Gosh still not working on my end... Do you think it has anything to do with the script? But it works just fine if I open up in terminal `/home/pi/Desktop/newBAC0` , and run `python test.py`

Comment: On my crontab program, its just `15 * * * * sudo /home/pi/Desktop/newBAC0/test.py` and I used the `crontab -e` like you recommended and i know it saved properly.. Any tips help! Thank you

Comment: One other thought that ran across my head, is I recently installed berry conda which is Python 3.6 but I think Python 3.5 is still installed on the pi. Would it be possible that 3.5 is running when crontab executes? I dont have the specific packages installed on 3.5 if it is even on the pi... Any idea on how to confirm?

Comment: I think that the different version issue is quite a possibility.  Try writing a simple python script that will write the version of Python is using to a file so you will know which version it is using.  Or add those packages to 3.5  You might also use Python's "try" & "except" methods to write the error message to a file.  That could be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the problem lies in the way to call the editor.

If what you want to change is the crontab root, you must edit it with

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and with:

```
crontab -e
```

the user's