# Pygame.mixer does not play sound when started in cron

Tags: python, audio, cron, pygame

I have written a small python script that plays a track after the press of a button (and ignores further button presses until the track has completed). The script works perfectly fine when started from terminal, but I simply cannot find a way to make it start on reboot with cron.
Here is the script `hoelderlinbutton.py`:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
music = pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/pi/Hoelderlin.mp3")
from signal import pause
from gpiozero import Button
def on_press ():
   if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
      pygame.mixer.music.play()
button = Button(2)
button.when_pressed = on_press
pause()
```

The relevant line in crontab -e is:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/hoelderlinbutton.py
```

Upon reboot, nothing happens after pressing the button. I've activated cron logging ([Where do Cron error message go?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3741/where-do-cron-error-message-go)) but the log indicates that the script was executed. I tried to log for any errors from the script by changing the line in crontab to this:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/hoelderlinbutton.py > /home/pi/logs/backup.log 2>&1
```

But the created log file is empty.

I then experimented, based on various hints and ideas from previous posts and answers by:

- using either `sudo crontab -e` or `crontab -e`;
- changing the working directory in crontab with `@reboot cd /home/pi && /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/hoelderlinbutton.py`;
- Executing the script in the background by appending  `&` at the end;
- Setting`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000` earlier in crontab -e or sudo crontab -e (see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio#Play_sound_from_a_non-interactive_shell_.28systemd_service.2C_cron.29
- Executing the script for user pi in sudo crontab -e, i.e. `@reboot sudo -u pi /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/hoelderlinbutton.py` (See [No methods for running python script on startup are working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47526/no-methods-for-running-python-script-on-startup-are-working))

But none of this got me anywhere. I'm a little out of my depth here, but I believe that some limitation in the crontab environment prevents the actual playing of the track (or perhaps causes an issue with the GPIO). Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: Start the program from the GUI autostart not from Cron. `sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [Dougie's](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/94397/dougie) proposal works -- I wish I had asked earlier!
I removed the crontab entries and instead edited the autostart configuration with

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

and then added

```
@/usr/bin/python /home/pi/hoelderlibutton.py
```

in the second-to-last line. And then all is working perfectly!
In the longer term, I'd love to understand why it did not function in cron -- but for now I'm just happy to have this working. Thanks, Dougie!

Comment: This same approach worked for me when facing a similar problem with `simpleaudio` and `pyaudio` so it's not exclusively useful for `pygame` scripts.